# Firebase JS how do I collect the children of the product that each child has a quantity?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have products that evrey product have children and evrey child have children and i want to collect the sum for evrey product
[image]

my code is:

```
var firebaseProductsCollection = database.ref().child('finalVerifoneProducts');
firebaseProductsCollection.on('value', function(products) {
  products.forEach(function(firebaseProductReference) {
    code = firebaseProductReference.key;
    products.forEach(function(firebaseProductReference) {
      var code = firebaseProductReference.key;
      var firebaseGetBarcodes = database.ref().child('finalVerifoneProducts').child(code);
      firebaseGetBarcodes.on('value', function(productsBarcodes) {
        productsBarcodes.forEach(function(firebaseProductReference2) {
              var product = firebaseProductReference2.val();
              if (!productArray.includes(product.code)) {
                // we have new product 
                console.log(product.code + " : " + totalSum);
                productArray.push(product.code);
                totalSum = product.sum;
              } else {
                totalSum = parseInt(totalSum) + parseInt(product.sum);
              } // close the else
```

But the quantity of the first product is always 0 and the rest of the products gets wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load a path from the database, all data under that path is already included in the snapshot you get back. So there's no need to separate load the nested child data.

Knowing that, you can significantly simplify your code to:

```
const firebaseProductsCollection = database.ref().child('finalVerifoneProducts');
firebaseProductsCollection.on('value', function(products) {
  let totalSum = 0; // 
  products.forEach(function(productSnapshot) {
    code = productSnapshot.key;
    productSnapshot.forEach(function(productChildSnapshot) {
      var product = productChildSnapshot.val();
      totalSum += product.sum;
    });
  });
  console.log(totalSum); // 
});
```